How to run object detection with TensorFlow on Flutter Dart?
Currently, I am trying to build an object detection with flutter dart and tensorflow.
My pubspec.yaml is as follows:
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
tflite: ^1.1.2
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
image: ^4.2.0
I encountered this error when I tried to run IOS application.
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _TFLGpuDelegateCreate
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _TFLGpuDelegateDelete
Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
I wondered if the application encountered this because there is something wrong with the tflite library from flutter. How to resolve this problem and what would be the easy way to run some TensorFlow model on Flutter Dart mobile application?
Some more information:

Flutter is successfully installed. (confirmed by flutter doctor)
I can run Android application successfully. (can see the app built although there is no object detection features yet, just want to see if the library is installed and ran successfully).
Only the set up with IOS returns error. Can see the simulator of IOS.


